# Problems with Python Interactive Window Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was solving an exercise in python using Visual Studio Code, to creat a triangle with asterisks:

```
h = int(input('Introduce el nro de líneas para el triángulo isósceles:'))

for i in range(h):
    espacios = h - i
    asteriscos = 2 * i + 1
    print(' ' * espacios + '*' * asteriscos)
```

But, when I run in Python Interactive Window, there is a problem: first line printed not considered spaces:

[image: Problem in Python interactive window]

This same code in Jupyter Notebook or Spyder works fine.

Comment: Looks like a "quirk" of Visual Studio Code — would call it a bug, myself…

Comment: It can be fixed? I was able to solve it by writing print () before loop For, but is garbage line.

Comment: Adding a dummy `print()` is what's known as a workaround. You should report the issue as a bug to MS, in my opinion.